# unset session in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, session

I need to unset the multivalued session in magento, because i have added a large amount of values into session on the based of particular params like:

```
 $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSummaryParameters($postData);
        Mage::unregister('ajax');
        Mage::unregister('ajax_result');
        Mage::register('ajax_summary',true); 
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMassageType($postData['type']);
        $masseur = $postData['name'];
        $productId = $postData['id'];
         $aw_booking_date = $postData['day'];
         $parameters['product'] = $productId;

         // prepare arguments for book now button based on selected data of reservation page
         $parameters['aw_booking_from_display'] = $aw_booking_date;
         $parameters['aw_booking_from'] = $aw_booking_date;

         $parameters['aw_booking_time_from[hours-am]'] = 12;
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_from[hours-pm]'] = 12;
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_from[hours]'] = date('h',strtotime($postData['time']));
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_from[minutes]'] = date('i',strtotime($postData['time']));
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_from[daypart]'] = date('a',strtotime($postData['time']));

         $time = strtotime($postData['time']);
         $minutes = '+'.$postData['minutes'].' minutes';
         $to_time = date("H:i", strtotime($minutes, $time));
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_to[hours-am]'] = 12;
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_to[hours-pm]'] = 12;
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_to[hours]'] = date('h',strtotime($to_time));;
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_to[minutes]'] = date('i',strtotime($to_time));;
         $parameters['aw_booking_time_to[daypart]'] = date('a',strtotime($to_time));;
         $parameters['qty'] = 1;
```

but when i refresh the page or comes different page to action controller page it gives me 
mysql syntax error. because now session have no value with valid params, 
please tell me how i can unset the session as i register.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh god finally i got the answer of this question,

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsSummaryParameters();
```